# Testing a function called on an object with Jest in React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

**EDIT**

Current example,

```
  it('CALLED THE canOpenURL FUNCTION', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ResourceCardComponent {...mockProps} />);
    const canOpenURLSpy = jest.spyOn(Linking, 'canOpenURL');
    wrapper.find('TouchableOpacity').simulate('click');
    expect(canOpenURLSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    canOpenURLSpy.mockReset();
    canOpenURLSpy.mockRestore();
  });
```

*Error*

> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled() Expected mock function to have
>   been called.

**Problem**

I am using `Jest` & `Enzyme` to test a class made with `React Native`. This class has a function inside of it that when fired off uses the Linking library to call `canOpenUrl` and `openUrl`. I can simulate the click event on the mounted component but I am having trouble knowing how much of this I can actually test.

My goal is to check if `Linking.canOpenUrl` ever fires off.

**Exmaple**

The function inside the component looks like this,

```
  onPressLink() {
    console.log('HEY THIS FUNCTION FIRED WOOT WOOT');
    Linking.canOpenURL(this.props.url).then((supported) => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(this.props.url);
      }
    });
  }
```

I can simulate this firing off like this,

```
describe('onPressLink has been called!', () => {
  it('It clicks the mock function onPressLink!', (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...mockProps} />);
    const onPressLink = jest.fn();
    const a = new onPressLink();
    wrapper.find('TouchableOpacity').first().simulate('click');
    expect(onPressLink).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

Now that does work, but my goal is to use something like this,

```
expect(Linking.canOpenUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But I keep getting this error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined

Current code that is trying to check if this function is ever fired off. Which is inside the parent function that is clicked with the simulate method,

```
  it('calls canOpenURL', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...mockProps} />);
    const canOpenURL = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance, 'onPressLink');
    wrapper.find('TouchableOpacity').simulate('click');
    expect('Linking.canOpenUrl').toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**Question**

What is the proper way to check to see if `Linking.canOpenURL` is fired when its parent function is executed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Since Jest 19.0.0+)*

You can spy on the Linking module methods using `jest.spyOn()`.

(1) Tell jest to spy on the module method:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(Linking, 'canOpenURL');
```

(2) After doing everything you need to test it, check the spy:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

(3) Clean up and stop spying on the module method

```
spy.mockReset();
spy.mockRestore();
```

---

If you don't want the tests to use the actual implementation of the methods, you can fake them like this:

```
jest.spyOn(Linking, 'canOpenURL').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());
```

Where the function passed to mockImplementation will be whatever you want the method to do when called.

Ref https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname

---

When using the actual implementation of your module method, which is asynchronous, the promise might not have been resolved by the time you tested it. You need to make sure any promise is resolved in your method implementation before making any assertions on it.

One way to deal with this is using async/await, like so:

```
it('...', async () => {
  // Wait for promise to resolve before moving on
  await wrapper.instance().onPressLink();

  // make your assertions
  expect(...);
});
```

Another option is using `expect().resolves`, [available since Jest 20.0.0](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#resolves), where you wait for some promise in the argument to expect() to resolve with a value before making an assertion on that value.

```
expect(somePromiseThatEventuallyResolvesWithValue).resolves.toBe(Value);
```

Comment: Please see my edit at the top. Thanks for your help. But that does not appear to work. When using this exact method we have been getting this, expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled() - Expected mock function to have been called.

Comment: @wuno did you try using mockImplementation? Looks to me like a typical asynchronous issue. You are testing before the promise resolves. Why don't you try also async/await? `it('should...', async () => { await wrapper.instance().onPressLink(); /* then test afterward */ })`

Comment: I actually got it working with resolve. Would you mind adding this to your answer for the next person? Since it was returning a promise it looked like this, xpected value to be (using ===):
      true
    Received:
      {"_40": 0, "_55": true, "_65": 1, "_72": null} So I added resolve and it worked, expect(linkOpen).resolves.toBe(true);

Answer (score 1):

I've done in simplest way:

**Steps to spy:**

1. Make spy object for original function using **jest**
2. Call original function with / without argument(s)
3. Assert the function which should be called with valid argument(s)
4. Reset mock
5. Restore mock

#### Here is the sample example

**DefaultBrowser.ts** which is actual class.

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

export const openDefaultBrowser = async url => {
  if (await Linking.canOpenURL(url)) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
  }
};
```

**DefaultBrowser.test.ts** which is test case class.

```
import { openDefaultBrowser } from '../DefaultBrowser';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

describe('openDefaultBrowser with validate and open url', () => {
  it('validate url', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Linking, 'canOpenURL');
    openDefaultBrowser('https://www.google.com');
    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith('https://www.google.com');
    spy.mockReset();
    spy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('open url', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Linking, 'openURL');
    openDefaultBrowser('https://www.google.com');
    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith('https://www.google.com');
    spy.mockReset();
    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: We usually check if the provided URL is supported first. If its a supported URL then we proceeds to open it. The second test which tests the invocation of "openURL" is not going to pass because "canOpenURL" returns a promise. Please enlighten me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
  it('open url', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(Linking, 'canOpenURL')
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Linking, 'openURL')

    openURL(sitePath)

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(sitePath)
    })

    spy.mockReset()
    spy.mockRestore()
  })
```